# How do I target each circle within svg using css?

Tags: css, svg

I have this

```
<svg class="wheel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" transform="scale(1.022,1.022)" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" height="100%" width="100%">
<circle fill="#ffffff" cx="512" cy="512" r="110"></circle>
<circle stroke="#ffffff" r="456" fill="transparent" stroke-width="33" cx="512" cy="512"></circle>
</svg>
```

How can I style each circle using css? Thank you.

Comment: easiest if you give them both an id attribute

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the SVG markup won't change, then this will suffice:

```
.wheel * {
  // CSS here
}
```

Otherwise, give the circles a class and write like:

```
.wheel .wheel-circle {
  // CSS here
}
```

If you mean each circle needs different styles then simply:

```
.wheel #wheel-circle-1 {
  // CSS here
}

.wheel #wheel-circle-2 {
  // CSS here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1:

The best way would be to add an id to each circle:

```
<svg class="wheel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" transform="scale(1.022,1.022)" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" height="100%" width="100%">
 <circle id="innerCircle" fill="#ffffff" cx="512" cy="512" r="110"></circle>
 <circle id="outerCircle" stroke="#ffffff" r="456" fill="transparent" stroke-width="33" cx="512" cy="512"></circle>
</svg>
```

And then just target that.

```
#innerCircle {
  fill: red;
}

#outerCircle {
  stroke: blue;
}
```

### Method 2:

But if this is not desirable, try using the nth-child selector on the parent:

```
.wheel:nth-child(1) {
   fill: red;
}

.wheel:nth-child(2) {
  stroke: blue;
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: It should be `circle:nth-child` not .wheel:nth-child. You can also try `circle:nth-of-type` or you can target the circles in base of the attributes like `circle[fill = "#ffffff"]`